# Why was comment deleted without notice?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

I posted a comment on [Looking up whole time-series for specific point from 45 GB file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442182/looking-up-the-whole-time-series-for-a-specific-point-from-a-45-gb-file)

If I recall correctly, it had two parts. First a remark how I could not understand why someone had voted to close this well presented and clear question. Secondly a question to the person asking if they had a specific reason to use nearest interpolation instead of discrete coordinates.

You can see the person who asked the question actually refers to it in a follow up question but my comment is gone.

Why was my comment deleted without any notice?